# Weird "all" in"where"

Tags: mysql, sql

The problem exists in MySQL's newest version, so I even doubt that that may be a bug.

Here are two tables:

```
t1(id int), values (10),(2)
t2(id int), values (0),(null),(1)
```

Execute:

```
select id from t1 where id > all (select id from t2);
```

Return result set:

```
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|   10 |
|    2 |
+------+
```

According to my knowledge and the page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html

The statement should return empty result! Because each judgement in "where" leads to null, like this:

```
select id > all (select id from t2)  as c1 from t1;
```

returns:

```
+------+
| c1   |
+------+
| NULL |
| NULL |
+------+
```

and actually `select id from t1 where null;` returns nothing!

Finally, I tried this:

```
explain extended select id from t1 where id > all (select id from t2);
show warnings;
```

```
+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                                                                             |
+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1003 | select `test`.`t1`.`id` AS `id` from `test`.`t1` where <not>((`test`.`t1`.`id` <= (select max(`test`.`t2`.`id`) from `test`.`t2`))) |
+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

We can see that MySQL optimizes the original SQL to this one, which actually fits the result set.

but I not think the optimized SQL equals the original one .

Am I wrong?

Comment: I agree with you. Bug in MySQL. The transformation in Michael's answer [is not semantically valid in the presence of nulls.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11492653/73226)

Comment: BTW: For me on `5.1.48-community` the following query returns no rows as expected `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE 10 > ALL (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT NULL)` and the explain plan says "Impossible Where". What version are you on?

Comment: @MartinSmith MySQL(by internally transforming the `> ALL` on WHERE clause to a `MAX` construct) had made the invalid valid ;-) Hatin' MySQL now, it can redeem itself though, as you've stated it returns empty row now on version `5.1.48-community`. +1 to your insights, it's a bug of MySQL(older version), it's a flawed design

Comment: @MichaelBuen - I can reproduce the issue in `5.1.48-community` though if I create a table and use that in the sub query rather than literal values so it seems that must use a different (incorrect) code path. Either way clear indication that it must be a bug rather than a deliberate deviation from the standard.

Comment: test http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/1131 (method I learned from Michael :) ).On 5.5.25,We can get the same result. Surprising. Thank you for your passion to solve my problem,both Michael and Martin.It's weird that I can't register in dev.mysql.com. Would you like to deliver the bug to the support team? ;-)

Comment: @carl: +1 for catching this bug. I'm surprised no-one had found it previously.

Comment: [Reported for you on the bug tracker](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65902)

Answer (score 8):

**Update**: Upon further analysis and unfolding of MySQL's `> ALL` odd implementation. This answer should be considered as MySQL-specific. So for further disclaimer, explanation on answer here regarding `> ALL` is not applicable to other RDBMSes (unless there are other RDBMSes that copied MySQL implementation). Internal translation from `> ALL` to a `MAX` construct, applies to MySQL only.

This:

```
select id from t1 where id > all (select id from t2);
```

is semantically equivalent to:

```
select id from t1 where id > (select max(id) from t2);
```

Since `select max(id) from t2` returns 1, the second query materializes to this:

```
select id from t1 where id > 1
```

That's why it returns both `10` and `2` from table t1

---

One of the instances where NULL rules is being applied is when you use `NOT IN`, an example:

DDL:

```
create table t1(id int);

insert into t1 values (10),(2);


create table t2(id int); 

insert into t2 values (0),(null),(1);
```

Query:

```
select * from t1 where id not in (select id from t2);

-- above is evaluated same as the following query, so the rules about null applies,
-- hence the above and following query will not return any record.    

select * from t1 where id <> 0 and id <> null and id <> 1;



-- to eliminate null side-effect, do this:
select * from t1 where id not in (select id from t2 where id is not null);

-- which is equivalent to this:
select * from t1 where id <> 0 and id <> 1;
```

The last two queries returns `10` and `2`, whereas the first two queries returns empty set

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82865/1

Hope these examples erases your confusion with NULL rules.

---

Regarding

> but I not think the optimized sql equals the original one .

Optimized sql being this:

```
select `test`.`t1`.`id` AS `id` from `test`.`t1` where <not>((`
test`.`t1`.`id` <= (select max(`test`.`t2`.`id`) from `test`.`t2`)))
```

That is really equivalent to your original query: `select id from t1 where id > all (select id from t2);`

The construct `t1.field > all (select t2.field from t2)` is just a syntactic sugar for:

```
t1.field > (select max(t2.field) from t2)
```

If you will apply DeMorgan theorem on the optimized SQL by MySql:

```
not (t1.id <= (select max(t2.id) from t2))
```

That is equivalent to:

```
t1.id > (select max(t2.id) from t2)
```

Which in turn is equivalent to the syntactic sugar `ALL`:

```
t1.id > ALL(select t2.id from t2)
```

Comment: The initial 'semantically equivalent' rewrite of the query is only valid if the subquery can never contain a NULL.  If the subquery can return nulls, the rewrite is not valid.

Comment: here comes the difference between common logic in sql and actual engines behaviours...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I concur. It's the flawed implementation(by internally transforming `> ALL` to `MAX` construct) of MySQL that muddles up the NULL rules on `ALL` subquery. The *semantically equivalent* only holds true when the subquery **don't have any NULLs** in it, otherwise they are different beast altogether. Perhaps to make a better analogy, MySQL(old version)'s ALL is a chimera ツ

Comment: RE: chimera. I might mean chupacabara there ツ

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in MySQL ([Reported and verified here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65902)).

> The fix will be available in 5.6.7 (next 5.6x version) as well as in
>   the next major tree (5.7x)

It [differs from the stated behaviour in the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc//refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html) and that prescribed in the ANSI standard.

Moreover it is not even consistent in MySQL and you get different results when the sub query references a table compared to when the sub query contains (the same) literal values.

```
CREATE TABLE t2
  (
     id INT
  );

INSERT INTO t2
VALUES      (0),
            (NULL),
            (1);

/*Returns row with 10*/
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT 10 AS id) T
WHERE  id > ALL (SELECT id
                 FROM   t2);

/*Returns no rows. Explain Plan says "Impossible Where"*/
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT 10 AS id) T
WHERE  id > ALL (SELECT 0
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT NULL
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1);
```

The second behaviour is correct per the spec. How `10 > ALL( (0),(null),(1) )` ought to be logically evaluated as follows

```
10 > 0 =  TRUE
10 > NULL =  UNKNOWN
10 > 1 =  TRUE
```

Under the rules of three valued logic

```
TRUE AND UNKNOWN AND TRUE = UNKNOWN
```

So this row should **not** be returned. [See the ANSI specification](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) which clearly states

> The result of "`R <comp op> <quantifier> T`" is derived by the
>   application of the implied `<comparison predicate>` "`R <comp op> RT`" to
>   every row `RT` in `T`:

Therefore this is not a semantically valid optimisation when `T` is Nullable. The full section of the spec is reproduced below.

> 8.7
>
> ```
>      Function
>
>      Specify a quantified comparison.
>
>      Format
>
>      <quantified comparison predicate> ::=
>           <row value constructor> <comp op> <quantifier> <table subquery>
>
>
>      <quantifier> ::= <all> | <some>
>
>      <all> ::= ALL
>
>      <some> ::= SOME | ANY
>
>
>      Syntax Rules
>
>      1) The <row value constructor> shall be of the same degree as the
>         result of the <table subquery>.
>
>      2) The data types of the values of the <row value constructor>
>         shall be respectively comparable to those of the columns of the
>         <table subquery>.
>
>      3) The collating sequence for each pair of respective values in
>         the <quantified comparison predicate> is determined in the same
>         manner as described in Subclause 8.2, "<comparison predicate>".
>
>      Access Rules
>
>         None.
>
>      General Rules
>
>      1) Let R be the result of the <row value constructor> and let T be
>         the result of the <table subquery>.
>
>      2) The result of "R <comp op> <quantifier> T" is derived by the
>         application of the implied <comparison predicate> "R <comp op>
>         RT" to every row RT in T:
>
>         Case:
>
>         a) If T is empty or if the implied <comparison predicate> is
>           true for every row RT in T, then "R <comp op> <all> T" is
>           true.
>
>         b) If the implied <comparison predicate> is false for at least
>           one row RT in T, then "R <comp op> <all> T" is false.
>
>         c) If the implied <comparison predicate> is true for at least
>           one row RT in T, then "R <comp op> <some> T" is true.
>
>         d) If T is empty or if the implied <comparison predicate> is
>           false for every row RT in T, then "R <comp op> <some> T" is
>           false.
>
>         e) If "R <comp op> <quantifier> T" is neither true nor false,
>           then it is unknown.
> ```

Comment: +1 This explains it well. MySQL's `ALL` had almost reinvented my notion of null handling on `ALL` subquery :D Its internal translation of `ALL` to `MAX` really muddled up my understanding of null handling on `ALL` subquery

Answer (score 4):

**Update** (2012-07-15) The problem is confined to MySQL only, perhaps I was confused while tabbing between many sqlfiddle tabs on Chrome. There's no problem on Postgresql, its NULL behavior is consistent on both its SELECT and WHERE clause, same with Sql Server.

<strike>Adamantly, I'm as confused as you now,</strike>  I tried your MySql query on Sql Server: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82865/6

```
-- query 1
select 
    case when id > all(select id from t2) then 1 else 0 end as c1
from t1;


-- query 2
select 
    *
from t1
where id > all(select id from t2);
```

The first query returns `0` to all rows.

```
| C1 |
------
|  0 |
|  0 |
```

Naturally, the second query (which has a WHERE clause) should not return any rows. Which Sql Server rightfully do. <strike>While I don't agree with `0` as being the result for column `C1` (it should be `1`)</strike>, I applaud Sql Server for being consistent.

Then on your MySql query on both MySql ( http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82865/25 ) and Postgresql ( http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/82865/5 ):

```
-- query 1
select 
    id > all(select id from t2) as c1
from t1;


-- query 2
select 
    *
from t1
where id > all(select id from t2);
```

<strike>MySql and Postgresql both yielded same output:</strike>

MySql yield this output:

```
|     C1 |
----------
| (null) |
| (null) |


| ID |
------
| 10 |
|  2 |
```

<strike>I believe the second query has the correct output, but the embedded condition on SELECT clause(first query) indicates otherwise. I dislike this inconsistency.</strike>

**Striked paragraph amendment**: MySQL has the problem. Postgresql implementation is correct, both its SELECT clause and WHERE clause yields the same result, it returns NULLs on SELECT, and it return empty row on WHERE clause.

Now, I wanted to ask this question on <strike>Postgresql or</strike>  MySql forums why there is discrepancy on results between a condition on WHERE clause and a condition embedded on SELECT clause.

I hope there's a kindred soul in stackoverflow who can further explain this **inconsistency** for us :-)

---

<strike>No matter how sweet the syntatic sugar `ALL` is, I'm not inclined to use it anymore. It has inconsistent result between on WHERE clause and embedded on SELECT. I uses `MAX` on all my queries anyway, IMHO the intent is clearer than English-like `ALL`, the more reason I need to continue using `MAX`:</strike>

**Striked paragraph amendment**: We should not develop aversion to `ALL` just because MySQL has flawed implementation ;-)

On both MySql and Postgresql, MAX yield the same output

```
-- Query 1
select 
    id > all(select id from t2) as c1,
    id > (select max(id) from t2) as c2
from t1;


-- Query 2
select 
    *
from t1
where id > all(select id from t2);


-- Query 3
select 
    *
from t1
where id > (select max(id) from t2);
```

The `MAX` output is consistent on both RDBMS.

```
-- Query 1 output:

|     C1 | C2 |
---------------
| (null) |  1 |
| (null) |  1 |



-- Query 2 output:

MySql return this:

| ID |
------
| 10 |
|  2 |

Postgresql return empty row. Which is correct



-- Query 3 output:

| ID |
------
| 10 |
|  2 |
```

---

---

Furthermore, `MAX` is **consistent** among all RDBMS:

```
select 
    case when id > all(select id from t2) then 'Yes' else 'Oh No!' end as c1,
    case when id > (select max(id) from t2) then 'Yes' else 'Oh No!' end as c2
from t1;


select 
    *
from t1
where id > all(select id from t2);


select 
    *
from t1
where id > (select max(id) from t2);
```

Live test:

- Sql Server: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/82865/10
- MySql: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82865/29
- Postgresql: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/82865/7

---

---

To nail it, it's only MySQL that implements `id > ALL` to `id > (SELECT MAX`. Both Postgresql and Sql Server interprets `id > ALL(0,NULL,1)` as `id > 0 AND id > NULL AND id > 1`, hence both Postgresql and Sql Server yields same output.

Illumination on NULL rules come from Martin Smith insights on [NULL values are excluded. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491831/null-values-are-excluded-why#comment15180077_11491831)

MySQL's `ALL` problem is isolated to MySQL only, it's very inconsistent. MySQL translate `ALL` to `MAX` on its WHERE clause; while on its SELECT clause, MySQL translate `ALL` to *chained* ANDs.

Other RDBMSes implement `> ALL` as *chained* ANDs, rules on NULL on ALL expression applies to both of their SELECT clause and WHERE clause, they have consistent results on both SELECT clause and WHERE clause. And their rules on `NULL` on `ALL` is ANSQL SQL-compliant

Comment: Thanks a lot! Before this problem ,I thought I knew how "NULL" works.But this confused me. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/all-subqueries.html There is an example just look like this,but the conclusion is different from yours."The expression is unknown (that is, NULL) if table t2 contains (0,NULL,1). "  Who can help? Or this is a bug ?!

Comment: "Who can help?" There are some MySql and Postgresql core devs on Stackoverflow, I hope they get to see this question and answer. It feels like a bug, I didn't expect the SELECT clause can't mirror what's happening on WHERE clause; however, seeing exactly same results on both MySql and Postgresql, I can't be 100% sure

Comment: @carl Found the answer, it's a flaw on MySQL part only. Upon further inspection, Postgresql's output is not similar to MySQL, perhaps I was confused while switching between multiple browser tabs on sqlfiddle. There's no problem on both Postgresql and Sql Server, they have the same output. See the update on this answer