# NULL values are excluded. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is about a bizarre behaviour I found in Microsoft Sql Server. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLEA 
WHERE [Column1] IS NULL;
```

This returns 30018 rows.

```
CREATE VIEW VIEWB AS 
SELECT * FROM TABLEA AS t1 
WHERE t1.[Column1] NOT IN ('Cross/Up sell', 'Renegotiation', 'Renewal')
```

If I check `VIEWB`, I don't find `NULL` in `Column1`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VIEWB 
WHERE [Column1] IS NULL;
```

This returns 0 rows.

Why? The query above excludes the 3 values, but **it isn't supposed to exclude NULL**. Why does Ms Sql Server behave this way? Should I have expected this?
How can I fix it?

Comment: What does this do:

    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLEA AS t1
    WHERE t1.[Column1] NOT IN ('Cross/Up sell', 'Renegotiation', 'Renewal')

Comment: The answer, as pointed by Martin Smith and Sumo is that **it is supposed to exclude NULL**, because **`NULL` is not a value**.

Comment: Another stackoverfellow has a somewhat similar problem with NULL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462716/weird-all-inwhere/ Interpreting rules on NULL is very confusing. I'm hoping there's someone who could mention what rules do ANSI SQL have regarding NULL interpretation on queries

Comment: @MichaelBuen - I think your answer there is wrong. It is only semantically equivalent to make that transformation if the column is not nullable. SQL Server would return no rows as the OP expects. (Edit just noticed you gave a second answer along those lines)

Comment: @MartinSmith Regarding the NULL on `NOT IN` and `IN`, I've already knew the rules around it. It's the rules about `ALL` that trips me up, IIRC, `ALL` is translated internally to `MAX`, hence rules about NULLs on `MAX` (nulls are discarded) applies to `ALL` too.. or so I thought. It turns out upon further testing on the 3 RDBMS, there's a difference, the 3 RDBMS are consistent with `MAX`, but not with `ALL`

Comment: @MichaelBuen - It looks like that is an optimisation that MySQL is doing but I'm pretty sure that is not a valid optimisation according to the ANSI spec. It should just be expanded out into and `AND`-ed. List `NOT IN` is equivalent to `<> ALL` and `C > ALL((1),(2),(NULL))` should be `C > 1 AND C > 2 AND C > NULL` which is `unknown`

Comment: @MartinSmith Your last example made it clear, symmetrical to my knowledge on `IN`/`NOT IN`: "`C > ALL((1),(2),(NULL))` should be `C > 1 AND C > 2 AND C > NULL` which is unknown". I should discard my old notion that `> ALL` is directly translated to `MAX` construct; yet perhaps on some RDBMS this implementation(`> ALL` translated to `MAX`) holds true, even though the standards doesn't uphold their implementation

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is actually a common mistake made with SQL Server in treating NULL as a value.  By default, it's treated as UNKNOWN, as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191270%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  So, in your view, you also need to include an `OR t1.[Column1] IS NULL`.

You can change this behavior by calling `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`.  It is not recommended to use this, however, as the feature is deprecated as pointed out by @Martin Smith.

This is not a SQL Server specific issue, however.  It's part of the [ANSI SQL standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Null_and_three-valued_logic_.283VL.29).

Comment: `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` is worth mentioning for completeness but is deprecated and has the following warning in the docs. `Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.`

Answer (score 13):

SQL uses [three valued logic](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/).

```
t1.[Column1] NOT IN ('Cross/Up sell', 'Renegotiation', 'Renewal')
```

is equivalent to

```
t1.[Column1] <> 'Cross/Up sell' AND  
t1.[Column1] <> 'Renegotiation' AND 
t1.[Column1] <>  'Renewal')
```

When `t1.[Column1] is NULL` this expression evaluates to `UNKNOWN` rather than `TRUE` so these rows are not returned.

The only time `NULL NOT IN ( ... )` will be returned is if the `NOT IN` clause evaluates to an empty set.

Comment: VIEWB should show all records where Column1 is not one of the three values. Meaning, it should include records where column1 is NULL, but apparently it's not doing that.

Comment: @MikeFulton - when column1 is `NULL` it is treated as unknown whether or not it is one of those values. SQL uses `TRUE/FALSE/UNKNOWN`. The `WHERE` clause only returns rows where the predicate evaluates to true.

Answer (score 8):

Best answer would be just to use below condition in where clause

**ISNULL(t1.[Column1],'')** NOT IN ('Cross/Up sell', 'Renegotiation', 'Renewal')

Answer (score 1):

Another example of taking care when dealing with `nulls`

I'm just agreeing with Sumo - why not just change the view to:

```
CREATE VIEW VIEWB AS 
SELECT * FROM TABLEA AS t1 
WHERE 
    t1.[Column1] NOT IN ('Cross/Up sell', 'Renegotiation', 'Renewal')  
    OR
    t1 IS NULL
```

an alternative might be the following which I've added to [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8efab/1)

```
CREATE VIEW VIEWB AS 
SELECT * FROM TABLEA AS t1 
WHERE 
    1 = CASE 
          WHEN ISNULL(t1.[Column1],'x') NOT IN ('Cross/Up sell', 'Renegotiation', 'Renewal') THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way when dealing with null values. We can use

```
coalesce(t1.[Column1], ' ') not in ('Cross/Up sell', 'Renegotiation', 'Renewal')
```

Comment: What's the benefit of this approach? Can you [edit] your answer to include details?