# Select Not Including Nulls when not explicitly stated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-null

When I use

```
Select Distinct Brand_ID
from db.ABC
WHERE
Brand_ID <> 800
```

I get the returned output:

```
+----------+
| Brand_ID |
+----------+
|      100 |
|      200 |
|      300 |
|      400 |
|      500 |
|      600 |
|      700 |
|      900 |
+----------+
```

However, the column does contain NULL Values, which are present.
I need to update my select statement to explicitly say:

```
Select Distinct Brand_ID
from db.ABC
WHERE
Brand_ID <> 800 OR Brand_ID IS NULL
```

To get the correct output:

```
+----------+
| Brand_ID |
+----------+
| NULL     |
| 100      |
| 200      |
| 300      |
| 400      |
| 500      |
| 600      |
| 700      |
| 900      |
+----------+
```

Why does the `NULL` value get removed when not explicitly stated?

Comment: Great question, don't know the answer.

Comment: NULL is the absence of value.  In this case it is not <800 nor > 800

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491831/null-values-are-excluded-why

Comment: @sgeddes That's the one I was looking for!

Comment: @GregdeLima This functionality always annoyed me until I really thought about what NULL means. NULL signifies that a value is unknown or unavailable. So True/False value statements are not defined. If I don't know how much money I have, I have NULL money. That's not the same as having no money. I may have 27 dollars, I may not, so the truth value of "I have 27 dollars" is unknown rather than true or false.

Comment: @Error_2646 - 100% agreed, just needed to reframe the thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL `NULL` means

> I don't know

so `NULL` isn't a value.

Comment: So simple, but never thought about it.

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes `NULL` is a special one in SQL

Comment: Yeah, silly of me.

Comment: simple and awesome!

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the NULL value get removed when not explicitly stated?

Because it is not true that `NULL <> 800`

As an unknown quantity, NULL might equal 800 or it might not.  The only thing known about it is that it `IS NULL`.  Any equality or non-equality test of NULL will always return false.

EDIT:   Here's a bizarre flash realization...NULL is the Schroedinger's Cat of the SQL Universe.   : )

Answer (score 1):

That's how SQL NULL comparison works. The NULL is eliminated in your where clause.
This is also because of SET ANSI_NULL ON setting.
By default it is ON.

See an **[excellent explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766717/in-sql-server-what-does-set-ansi-nulls-on-mean)** here

You can try your query by stating

```
SET ANSI_NULL OFF
GO
Select Distinct Brand_ID
from db.ABC
WHERE
Brand_ID <> 800
```

This will give correct output