# Nulls removed by backslash filter

Tags: sql, filter, null

I ran into a situation where null values got removed by a backslash. I did not find examples online so I figure I would share it.

```sql
create table test(col varchar(10))
insert into test values ('a'),(null),('b')
select * from test where col != '\'
```

| col |
| --- |
| a |
| b |

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NULL values are excluded. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491831/null-values-are-excluded-why)

Answer (score 3):

This is correct.  Almost any comparison to `NULL` results in `NULL` which is treated as false.  Standard SQL has a `NULL`-safe comparison operator:

```
select *
from test
where col is distinct from '\';
```

Most databases do not support this, so an explicit comparison is often needed:

```
select *
from test
where col <> '\' or col is null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer would be `NULL` can not pass through any expression except `IS NULL`.

You need to use `IS NULL` as follows:

```
select * from test where col != '\' or col is null
```